# When creating a Python bytearray from NumPy array, where does the extra data come from?

Tags: python, numpy, buffer, arrays, protocol-buffers

Consider two ways of naively making the same `bytearray` (using Python 2.7.11, but confirmed same behavior in 3.4.3 as well):

```
In [80]: from array import array

In [81]: import numpy as np    

In [82]: a1 = array('L',  [1, 3, 2, 5, 4])

In [83]: a2 = np.asarray([1,3,2,5,4], dtype=int)

In [84]: b1 = bytearray(a1)

In [85]: b2 = bytearray(a2)
```

Since both `array.array` and `numpy.ndarray` support the buffer protocol, I would expect both to export the same underlying data on conversion to `bytearray`.

But the data from above:

```
In [86]: b1
Out[86]: bytearray(b'\x01\x03\x02\x05\x04')

In [87]: b2
Out[87]: bytearray(b'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')
```

At first I thought maybe a naive call to `bytearray` on a NumPy array will inadvertently get some extra bytes due to data type, contiguity, or some other overhead data.

But even when looking at the NumPy buffer data handle directly, it still says size is 40 and gives the same data:

```
In [90]: a2.data
Out[90]: <read-write buffer for 0x7fb85d60fee0, size 40, offset 0 at 0x7fb85d668fb0>

In [91]: bytearray(a2.data)
Out[91]: bytearray(b'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')
```

The same failing happens with `a2.view()`:

```
In [93]: bytearray(a2.view())
Out[93]: bytearray(b'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')
```

I noted that if I gave `dtype=np.int32` then the length of `bytearray(a2)` is 20 instead of 40, suggesting that the extra bytes have to do with type information -- it's just not clear why or how:

```
In [20]: a2 = np.asarray([1,3,2,5,4], dtype=int)

In [21]: len(bytearray(a2.data))
Out[21]: 40

In [22]: a2 = np.asarray([1,3,2,5,4], dtype=np.int32)

In [23]: len(bytearray(a2.data))
Out[23]: 20
```

AFAICT, `np.int32` ought to correspond to the `array` `'L'` typecode, but any explanations about why not would be massively helpful.

How can one reliably extract only the part of the data that "should" be exported via the buffer protocol ... as in, the same as what the plain `array` data looks like in this case.

Comment: What do you mean by "should" be exported?  The buffer protocol just specifies how to get the data, it doesn't say anything about what the data should be.

Comment: Is this because numpy is 64 bit by default (16 nibbles) ? Try to change the byte order (big endian, little endian) and see what happens. See this http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you create your bytearray from the `array.array`, it is treating it as an iterable of ints, not as a buffer.  You can see this because:

```
>>> bytearray(a1)
bytearray(b'\x01\x03\x02\x05\x04')
>>> bytearray(buffer(a1))
bytearray(b'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00')
```

That is, creating a bytearray directly from the array gives you "plain" ints, but creating a bytearray from a buffer of the array gives you the actual byte representations of those ints.  Also, you cannot create a bytearray from an array that has ints that won't fit into a single byte:

```
>>> bytearray(array.array(b'L', [256]))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#38>", line 1, in <module>
    bytearray(array.array(b'L', [256]))
ValueError: byte must be in range(0, 256)
```

The behavior is still puzzling, though, because both `array.array` and `np.ndarray` support *both* the buffer protocol *and* iteration, yet somehow creating a bytearray from a `array.array` gets the data via iteration, while creating a bytearray from a `numpy.ndarray` gets the data via the buffer protocol.  There is presumably some arcane explanation for this switched priority in the C internals of these two types, but I have no idea what it is.

In any case, it's not really correct to say that what you're seeing with your `a1` is what "should" happen; as I showed above, the data `'\x01\x03\x02\x05\x04'` is not actually what `array.array` exposes via the buffer protocol.  If anything, the behavior with the numpy array is what you "should" get from the buffer protocol; it is the `array.array` behavior that is not consistent with the buffer protocol.

Comment: Iterating over a `numpy.ndarray` yields scalars of the array's dtype while an `array.array` of any integer typecode yields `int` values, hence the different behaviour.

Comment: I more meant that one behavior or other should be "the" expected way. In a least astonishment sense, it's not good that the simple call to bytearray differs for these two types. I would be happy if either one of the two behaviors was the expected default though. In my application, this just means I need to be wary of sticking in a bunch of `buffer` calls when dealing with `array.array`.

Comment: @Goyo What about the case when I used `int` as the numpy dtype .. and why are the total byte lengths 20 and 40 in the two numpy cases. It seems like more is going on that just a simple story of the array.array ints giving as few bytes as needed (namely 1) while numpy gives 4 bytes always ... that doesn't quite seem to be happening.

Comment: @Goyo: That still doesn't explain it, since `bytearray([np.int32(x) for x in 1, 2, 3])` still returns a bytearray with "plain" int values, unlike `bytearray(np.array([1, 2, 3], dtype=np.int32))`.  So it's not just a matter of the individual values.

Comment: @Mr.F: When you specify `int` as the dtype, numpy just picks a platform default numpy integer type, which is apparently `int64` in your case.  You can check the dtype of the resulting array to see what its dtype actually is.

Comment: Ah, yes, correct. That too is a bit weird. I bet it is extremely hard to get NumPy to have arbitrary precision integers as dtype, but it seems that `array` can use it.

Comment: @BremBarn you're right. The problem seems to be that `array` does not actually support the (new) buffer API, I think. From https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/buffer.html: "An array can only expose its contents via the old-style buffer interface".

Answer (score 5):

I get the same bytearray with both cases:

```
In [1032]: sys.version
Out[1032]: '3.4.3 (default, Mar 26 2015, 22:07:01) \n[GCC 4.9.2]'
In [1033]: from array import array

In [1034]: a1=array('L',[1,3,2,5,4])
In [1035]: a2=np.array([1,3,2,5,4],dtype=np.int32)

In [1036]: bytearray(a1)
Out[1036]: bytearray(b'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00')
In [1037]: bytearray(a2)
Out[1037]: bytearray(b'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00')
```

In both cases I have 5 numbers, which occupy 4 bytes each (as 32 bit integers) - 20 bytes.

`bytearray` is probably asking for the following methods (or something equivalent):

```
In [1038]: a1.tobytes()
Out[1038]: b'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00'
In [1039]: a2.tostring()
Out[1039]: b'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00'
```

I can remove the extra bytes by changing dtype:

```
In [1059]: a2.astype('i1').tostring()
Out[1059]: b'\x01\x03\x02\x05\x04'
```

---

https://docs.python.org/2.6/c-api/buffer.html

> Starting from version 1.6, Python has been providing Python-level buffer objects and a C-level buffer API so that any built-in or used-defined type can expose its characteristics. Both, however, have been deprecated because of various shortcomings, and have been officially removed in Python 3.0 in favour of a new C-level buffer API and a new Python-level object named memoryview.
>
> The new buffer API has been backported to Python 2.6, and the memoryview object has been backported to Python 2.7. It is strongly advised to use them rather than the old APIs, unless you are blocked from doing so for compatibility reasons.

Given these changes in the buffer interface it's not surprising that the older `array` module was not changed in 2.6 and 2.7, but changed in 3.0+.

Comment: You are correct. I did not re-check the `array.array` example in Python 3, only the NumPy example. This has to do with the way that `array.array` was reimplemented in Python 3 to directly support the buffer protocol. So it seems that this explains why `bytearray` treats it as an iterable instead in Python 2. `bytearray` must check first if the passed data supports direct buffer access (`array.array` does not in Python 2, you must use an indirect idiom). If it does, it gets the data as you show. If it *doesn't*, as in Python 2, *then* it fails over to treating it like an iterable of `int`s.

Comment: It is odd, though, that `bytearray` wouldn't check first if the passed data supported the old-style buffer protocol, and only after *both* buffer checks would it resort to iterating over the values. This whole topic turns out to be quite important if you are building a library that deals with buffers and also seeks to have compatibility with both Python 2 and Python 3.

Comment: It may be a matter of development history.  `array` module has been around forever, but with the growth of `numpy` it is something of a development backwater.  `bytearray` is new in 2.6.  And I think the concept of a buffer protocol belongs in Python3, with a certain amount of backporting to Py2.  In Py3, default strings are unicode, `bytestrings` are the special case.