# cant turn byte back to array

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np 

ar_1=np.array([23,27,44,56])

byte_ar=bytearray(ar_1)

print("Array :",ar_1)
print("Array to bytes :",byte_ar)

to_ar=np.array(byte_ar)

print("Back to array :",to_ar)
```

Output :

```
Array : [23 27 44 56]
Array to bytes : bytearray(b'\x17\x00\x00\x00\x1b\x00\x00\x00,\x00\x00\x008\x00\x00\x00')
Back to array : [23  0  0  0 27  0  0  0 44  0  0  0 56  0  0  0]
```

Why am I getting zeros between elements?

It should look like this:

```
Back to array : [23  27  44  56  ]
```

Comment: Remember to properly [mark up](/markdown) your post, and remember to talk about [what you already did](/help/how-to-ask) in terms of debugging and (re)searching. Please [edit] your post to address both those things.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When creating a Python bytearray from NumPy array, where does the extra data come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35833414/when-creating-a-python-bytearray-from-numpy-array-where-does-the-extra-data-com)